# Is there a way to know when pytest-html create the actual html file?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I would like to know when the html and asset folder are created, after running a test via pytest. Is there a way to know when the file is actually created? I have tried to use breakpoints in pycharm but I can't get the time when the file is actually created.

The whole point of knowing when the file is created, is because I want to copy it in a zip file.

Comment: Why not doing that after the tests are finished?

Comment: Good point; it was mostly to keep the zipping process inside the actual test file. Since I need to collect the files all the time and zip them I thought it would make sense to write the zipping function when pytest is done and keep all the code incapsulated in the actual module where the test suite reside.

Comment: Don't try to put a pipeline into a part of the same pipeline. Use a shell script or if it is getting complex any CI/CD solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I assumed there was an easy way to have pytest do one last operation after creating the html report, but it seems that it is not that straightforward in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML report is written in the `pytest_sessionfinish` hookimpl:

```
def pytest_sessionfinish(self, session):
    report_content = self._generate_report(session)
    self._save_report(report_content)
```

[Source](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html/blob/b5a02fb46268205d09dfb7af29116d015c4c41a1/pytest_html/plugin.py#L618-L620).

If you want to manipulate the report file in your own test run, you can do that by adding your own `pytest_sessionfinish` hookimpl, e.g.

```
import pathlib
import zipfile


def pytest_sessionfinish(session):
    htmlfile = session.config.getoption('htmlpath')
    if htmlfile is None:  # html report not wanted by user
        return
    htmlzip = pathlib.Path(htmlfile).with_suffix('.zip')
    with zipfile.ZipFile(htmlzip, 'w') as zip:
        zip.write(htmlfile)
        zip.write('assets/style.css')
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot! I wrote a hook but it was triggered when the tests were completed, not when the report was created; as such my output was including all the files except the actual HTML report